# Medicine terms for programmers

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm a programmer working on some medical software. 
I like to name my functions and variables with correct English. 
So now I have few questions:

- what is the difference between **study** and **examination** in medicine?
- how could I say correctly **referral for/to examination/study/hospital**?
- what is more correct **medical appointment** or **doctor's appointment**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *study* is where you look at lots of people's results, for example, and see if there is anything useful

> We studied the treatments of 100 patients and learned that tall people were more likely to hit their head on the low beams in the waiting room

An *examination* is where the doctor tests your pulse, listens to your heart etc to see what is wrong with you

> The doctor took me into his office for an examination

---

> The patient was referred to the hospital for a more detailed examination

---

Both are correct if you are seeing a Doctor (as opposed to a nurse, for example)

Generally you would be more likely to say a "Doctor's appointment" if going to a General Practice or local doctor, and you would say "Medical Appointment" if going to the hospital.

Comment: In my experience (AE), "Doctor's appointment" trumps "Medical appointment". While there is nothing wrong or incorrect about either, I'd suggest that the former is more natural-sounding.

Comment: In BE most people would tend to err toward Doctor's Appointment too, but will sometimes say Medical to be accurate.